# DesktopAppConverter error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument"

Tags: powershell, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I wholeheartedly hate Microsoft! I'm trying to convert my Win32 app to UWP. (My app is already in the Windows 10 store. This is an update.) Last time I converted it about a year ago using a PowerShell script taken from the Microsoft page. Today, this script no longer works. So having gone to the same page (which looks totally different now) I had to [reinstall their desktop bridge converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter), or whatever the hell it's called.

So after downloading and installing all prerequisites, I'm trying to follow their instructions to convert my MSI installer as such:

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Installer-AppName.msi" -Destination "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Converter2\OUTConverted" -PackageName "AppPkgName.AppName" -Publisher "CN=John A. Doe, O=John A. Doe, STREET=""123 1st Ave. #1"", L=City, S=ST, PostalCode=12345, C=US" -Version 1.2.3.0 -MakeAppx -Verbose
```

which gives me this error:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '7th'.

[image]

What the heck does it not like?

Is it the quotes in the `-Publisher` parameter? Well, if so, I have to use them to be able to sign the resulting `.appx` file so that I can test it before I upload it to the store. (I.e. to be able to sign with `signtool.exe` the publisher name must match exactly what's on the cert.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. Whoever else runs into it, the cert publisher must be enclosed in quotes if it contains spaces. So it turns into this:

```
-Publisher """CN=John A. Doe, O=John A. Doe, STREET=""""123 1st Ave. #1"""", L=City, S=ST, PostalCode=12345, C=US"""
```